# how to customize ion-toggle form circle to rect shape

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm new in ionic and i need to customize `ion-toggle` like this.

[image]

but i don't know how to change from [image] this.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks to @LeftyX for the custom style.

I've used [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280945/how-can-i-place-text-inside-an-ion-toggle) for add text to ion-toggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change a few `css` rules.
You've got 2 elements there: `.toggle .track` and `.toggle .handle`.

Below you will find some css which will change the border radius, width and animation. `.toggle .handle:before` will add a ionicon to the handle.

```
.toggle .track
{
      border-radius: 6px !important;
      width: 70px;
}

.toggle .handle
{
      border-radius: 6px !important;
      width: 32px !important;
      height: 32px !important;
      top: 4px !important;
}

.toggle .handle:before {
   font-family: "Ionicons";
   content: "\f13f" !important;
   top: -11px !important;
   left: -21.5px !important;
}

.toggle input:checked + .track .handle {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(28px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(28px, 0, 0);
}
```

Adding labels `SI` and `NO` to your `ion-toggle` won't be that easy and I guess it would require building a directive.

Anyway, this is the final result:

[image]

and the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Leftyx/pen/KdrMzP).