# Ionic: convert from select to toggle,toggle not working

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to change the select to toggle style in ionic 1. The problem is I do not know how to let the toggle to select Yes or No. 
Two things I need

1. The toggle yes and no selection must work the same as select which currently working
2. I need to show the 'Yes' and 'No' on the toggle. The preset of the toggle is 'No'

**abc.html**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-33">Baby</div>
    <div class="col col-66">
      <select ng-model="searchQuery.stockBaby" ng-init="searchQuery.stockBaby = '%'">
        <option value="%">Yes</option>
        <option value="S">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

<ion-toggle ion-toggle-text ng-model="searchQuery.stockBaby" ng-init="searchQuery.stockBaby = '%'">
    <div class="col col-33">Baby</div>
    <div class="col col-66">
  </ion-toggle>
```

Current view of select and toggle.  Select is working but toggle not
[image: Current select and toggle]. It does not work anyway.
Also, I need the word in the toggle

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I place text inside an ion-toggle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280945/how-can-i-place-text-inside-an-ion-toggle)

Comment: @vahidnajafi, I also have issue to convert select to toggle. Not duplicate if you read clearly