# Text inside toggle in ionic 2

Tags: sass, ionic2, toggle, ion-toggle

I want to add text inside the Toggle in ionic 2. A [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280945/how-can-i-place-text-inside-an-ion-toggle) is available in the web for Ionic v1 but nothing for v2. Any help.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Test</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="test"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: did you try setting the value of ion-toggle?

Comment: If you mean <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="test">Test</ion-toggle>, it does not work.